# Cannot pass values to ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I have a bidder class for a car auction and cannot seem to pass jtextfield values into the array when the user clicks the submit button. The bidder class is:

```
package abc;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Bidder extends User{
private String firstName, lastName, street, city, postcode, tel, eMail, cardMake, cardNo, expDate;
private int houseNo, csvNo;

public Bidder(){

}

public Bidder(String UN, String UP, int UT, String FN, String LN, int HN,
        String S, String C, String P, String T, String EM, String CM, String CN, String ED, int CSV ){
super (UN, UP, UT);

firstName = FN;
lastName = LN;
houseNo = HN;
street = S;
city = C;
postcode = P;
tel = T;
eMail = EM;
cardMake = CM;
cardNo = CN;
expDate = ED;
csvNo = CSV;
}
static ArrayList<Bidder> BidderArray = new ArrayList<Bidder>();


}
```

The values I am trying to pass to the array are as when a submit button is pressed are as follows:

```
 private void submitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {     

    boolean validEntries = true;


    String checkUserName = userName.getText();
    if (checkUserName.equals(""))
    {
        validEntries = false;
        userName.setBackground(Color.red);
    }
    String checkPassword = password.getText();
    if (checkPassword.equals(""))
    {
        validEntries = false;
        password.setBackground(Color.red);
    }
    try{
    int checkUserType = Integer.parseInt(userType.getText());
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        validEntries = false;
        userType.setBackground(Color.red);
    }
    String checkFirstName = firstName.getText();
    if (checkFirstName.equals(""))
    {
        validEntries = false;
        firstName.setBackground(Color.red);
    }
    String checkLastName = lastName.getText();
    if (checkLastName.equals(""))
    {
        validEntries = false;
        lastName.setBackground(Color.red);
    }
    try
    {
        int checkHouseNo = Integer.parseInt(houseNo.getText());
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        validEntries = false;
        houseNo.setBackground(Color.red);
    }
    String checkStreet = street.getText();
    if (checkStreet.equals(""))
    {
        validEntries = false;
        street.setBackground(Color.red);

    }
    String checkCity = city.getText();
    if (checkCity.equals(""))
    {
        validEntries = false;
        city.setBackground(Color.red);

    }
    String checkPostcode = postcode.getText();
    if (checkPostcode.equals(""))
    {
        validEntries = false;
        postcode.setBackground(Color.red);

    }
    String checkTel = tel.getText();
    if (checkTel.equals(""))
    {
        validEntries = false;
        tel.setBackground(Color.red);

    }
    String checkEMail = eMail.getText();
    if (checkEMail.equals(""))
    {
        validEntries = false;
        eMail.setBackground(Color.red);

    }
    String checkCardType = cardType.getText();
    if (checkCardType.equals(""))
    {
        validEntries = false;
        cardType.setBackground(Color.red);

    }
    String checkCardNo = cardNo.getText();
    if (checkCardNo.equals(""))
    {
        validEntries = false;
        cardNo.setBackground(Color.red);

    }
    String checkExpDate = expDate.getText();
    if (checkExpDate.equals(""))
    {
        validEntries = false;
        expDate.setBackground(Color.red);

    }
    try
    {
        int checkCSV = Integer.parseInt(csv.getText());
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        validEntries = false;
        csv.setBackground(Color.red);
    }

    Bidder bidder2 = new Bidder(userName, password, userType, firstName, lastName, houseNo, 
            street, city, postcode, tel, eMail, cardType, cardNo, expDate, csv);
    Bidder.BidderArray.add(bidder2);

}
```

Regards

Lee

Comment: Your code seems to be ok, maybe the issue is some uncaught exception or when reading the items from the array.

Comment: What happens when you run this? Is there an error? Are the values blank? If you debug, are the values of `userName`, `password`, etc. correct before you pass them to the constructor?

Comment: How is `submitActionPerformed` being called? Or is it being called? (As an ised, inside `submitActionPerformed`, shouldn't you be constructing and inserting the new `Bidder` object only when `validEntries` is `true`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the `csv` as the last argument when you should be passing `checkCSV`. I strongly recommend that you get rid of that humongous constructor and use setters instead. It will make for much more maintainable code and will go a long way toward avoiding these kinds of errors.

The class might then look something like this:

```
public class Bidder extends User{

    private String firstName, lastName, street, city, postcode, tel, eMail, cardMake, cardNo, expDate;
    private int houseNo, csvNo;

    public Bidder(){

    }

    public void setFirstName(String name) {
        this.firstName = name;
    }

    public void setLastPassword(String password) {
        this.lastName = password;
    }

    // etc. for all the fields.

    public void setCSV(int csv) {
        this.csvNo = csv;
    }

    // Setters for userName, userPassword, and userType go in class User

    static ArrayList<Bidder> BidderArray = new ArrayList<Bidder>();

}
```

and you would use it like this:

```
private void submitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {     

    boolean validEntries = true;
    String sVal;
    int iVal;
    Bidder bidder2 = new Bidder();

    sVal = userName.getText();
    if (sVal.equals(""))
    {
        validEntries = false;
        userName.setBackground(Color.red);
    } else {
        bidder2.setUserName(sVal);
    }
    sVal = password.getText();
    if (sVal.equals(""))
    {
        validEntries = false;
        password.setBackground(Color.red);
    } else {
        bidder2.setUserPassword(sVal);
    }

    // for an int value:
    try{
        iVal = Integer.parseInt(csv.getText());
        bidder2.setCSV(iVal);
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        validEntries = false;
        userType.setBackground(Color.red);
    }

    // etc. for all the other fields

    if (validEntries) {
        Bidder.BidderArray.add(bidder2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried the checkCSV, this isn't working. what what your thinking behind this? Would I not have to use checkHouseNo as well?

Comment: @LeeChant - Yes. In fact, I notice that you seem to be using the text fields instead of the values for all the arguments (you're using `userName` instead of `checkUserName`, etc.) Fix all of them and it should compile. However, you really should switch to using setters. I'll update my answer to show the beginning of how this would work.

Comment: Will give this a try @TedHopp, intrigued to see how the setters would work too

Comment: @LeeChant - I added a setter and sample usage for `csvNo` to show the pattern. You just have to use `int` types instead of `String`.

Comment: Thanks @TedHopp, it caused a few problems elsewhere but I've managed to resolve them and it's working

Answer (score 2):

```
idder bidder2 = new Bidder(userName, password, userType, firstName, lastName, houseNo, 
            street, city, postcode, tel, eMail, cardType, cardNo, expDate, csv);
```

Should be like ,check the last parameter,

```
idder bidder2 = new Bidder(userName, password, userType, firstName, lastName, houseNo, 
            street, city, postcode, tel, eMail, cardType, cardNo, expDate, checkCSV );
```